# Alfresco REST API

Tags: python, django, rest, alfresco

I am trying to get a script (Python using [requests](http://docs.python-requests.org/en/latest/)) working to do the following with Alfresco (Community v5.0.0 (d r99759-b2) schema 8022) installed locally. Sadly [Alfresco's REST API documentation](http://docs.alfresco.com/community5.0/references/RESTful-intro.html) is sparse and contains no examples whatsoever.

What I want is:

1. List all directories form an arbitrary point within a Site's document repository.
2. For each directory, I need all the documents therein and all possible versions. A list of `(file_name, version, {noderef})` would be great but as long as the information is there, I care not what it looks like.

This should allow me to get a unique {noderef} for a document.  Once I have this {noderef}, I should be able to get a URL to download this document.

*How can I do these (simple?) things?*

Comment: I think you're looking at the wrong set of docs - what happens if you [review the Alfresco Public REST API docs](http://docs.alfresco.com/5.0/pra/1/concepts/pra-resources.html) - do those not cover what you need?

Comment: @Gagravarr: Yes, I might have been looking at the wrong set... Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think that you have different options. More than the three that I will describe. I prefer the first two.

1) Implement your own webscript

This has the advantage that you can decide exactly what to return and how to navigate in the folder structure. To do what you need is enough a simple webscript written in javascript and free marker template. Or you can use Java if you prefer.
[Repository-tier web scripts](http://docs.alfresco.com/5.0/concepts/ws-overview.html)

2) Use CMIS

If you do not want to write your webscript, because there is not an OOTB REST API that does exactly what you need, it could be easier to use CMIS.
What you need to do can be easily implemented with cmis query.
As a starting point: [CMIS tutorials](https://forums.alfresco.com/forum/developer-discussions/alfresco-api/cmis-resources-tutorials-and-examples-03212012-1456) and [CMIS Documentation](http://docs.alfresco.com/4.2/pra/1/topics/cmis-welcome.html)

3) Use the available REST API

There are several API that you can use. The easiest way to find them is to access /alfresco/service/index as already suggested.
[Wiki - Alfresco API](https://wiki.alfresco.com/wiki/Repository_RESTful_API_Reference)

To get all the children, you can use for example:

```
http://<your-alfresco-server>/alfresco/service/api/forms/picker/node/workspace/SpacesStore/62ccab8f-20bc-4039-9b59-70e4192fbeb6/doclib
```

This returns for example (only a snippet of the response):

```
{
    "data":
    {
       "parent":
       {
           "type": "cm:folder",
           "isContainer": true,
           "name": "Company Home",
           "title": "Company Home",
           "description": "The company root space",
           "modified": "2015-11-24T01:13:48.132Z",
           "modifier": "System",
           "displayPath": "",
           "nodeRef": "workspace://SpacesStore/3e49a3f3-54e8-427c-a7e6-33eedf3cb479"
       },
        "items":
        [
            {
                "type": "cm:folder",
                "parentType": "cm:cmobject",
                "isContainer": true,
                "name": "Container Bank",
                "title": "Container Bank",
                "description": "Bank of Deal Container Folders",


                "modified": "2015-11-24T01:13:44.827Z",
                "modifier": "System",

                "displayPath": "\/Company Home",
                "nodeRef": "workspace://SpacesStore/09b3072a-e76d-427c-8465-e18a009279c8",
                "selectable" : true
            },
            {
                "type": "cm:folder",
                "parentType": "cm:cmobject",
                "isContainer": true,
                "name": "Data Dictionary",
                "title": "Data Dictionary",
                "description": "User managed definitions",


                "modified": "2015-11-26T22:40:27.078Z",
                "modifier": "System",

                "displayPath": "\/Company Home",
                "nodeRef": "workspace://SpacesStore/b6653365-0c1c-4fa7-a604-0ac302d2374a",
                "selectable" : true
            },
            .....
        ]
    }
}
```

This webscript has also other parameters that can be useful. If you want to see it at work, you can open an "object finder" (for example try to attach a document to a workflow). The popup window to browse the repository will call this webscript. For example in my case it executed the following call:

```
curl "http://192.168.64.150:8080/share/proxy/alfresco/api/forms/picker/node/workspace/SpacesStore/66704925-4b32-4c4c-953b-42c6f0f047ec/children?selectableType=cm:content&searchTerm=&size=1000&filterStatusGroups=null" -H "Cookie: JSESSIONID=D9D08EC75879F4807AFF0FF115702E07; alfLogin=1452880051; alfUsername3=admin" -H "Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate, sdch" -H "Accept-Language: en-US,en;q=0.8,it;q=0.6,en-GB;q=0.4" -H "User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/47.0.2526.106 Safari/537.36" -H "Accept: */*" -H "Referer: http://192.168.64.150:8080/share/page/site/evergreeen-entertainment-ltd/start-workflow" -H "X-Requested-With: application/x-www-form-urlencoded" -H "Connection: keep-alive" --compressed
```

To get all the versions of a node, you can for example use the following:

```
http://192.168.64.150:8080/alfresco/service/api/node/workspace/SpacesStore/687858da-c713-4739-8a3c-f322251ce00e/versions
```

Answer (score 3):

Whenever I need to work with the Rest API, I go to /alfresco/service/index. This shows all of the webscripts that Alfresco has deployed and gives some metainformation about them. You can use this to figure out what endpoints are available, what their parameters are, etc. Browsing by URI can be a good starting point...

Comment: Check out this TTL, and you will find out about the new api that is not included in the list you mentionned: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=LCw7fe1pVSw